# WPF targetinvocationexception was unhandled when try to populate ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding

I have my object that i want to insert into `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyData> collection{ get; set; }

this.DataContext = this;
collection= new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
```

Now here i have `Array` with my objects:

```
MyData[] array...
```

So here i try to add 1 object into my `ObservableCollection`

```
collection.Add(array[0]);
```

And received the `targetinvocationexception` exception

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Have you checked the **inner exception**?

Comment: Are you sure that collection is not null and array have at least one element when you try add element to collection?

Comment: The fact that the exception is coming from PresentationFramework.dll seems to hint at some problem with the view, not the collection. Is your ObservableCollection bound to some property in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error appears if you associate the DataContext before calling InitializeComponent method.
For example

```
public MainWindow() {
   timerViewModel = new TimerViewModel(new MyDateTime());
   timerLabel.DataContext = timerViewModel; //error
   InitializeComponent();    
}

public MainWindow() {
   timerViewModel = new TimerViewModel(new MyDateTime());
   InitializeComponent();
   timerLabel.DataContext = timerViewModel; //Ok
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it : 
(My answerd by this method) :

In outside scope,declare public :

```
public ObservableCollection<MyData> collection{ get; set; }
```

In Contructor :

```
this.DataContext = this;
collection= new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
```

MyDataArray is :

```
MyData[] array =
        {
            new MyData { MyProp = "A" },
            new MyData { MyProp = "B" },
            new MyData { MyProp = "C" }
        };
```

In button for add to list :

```
collection.Add(array[1]);
```

MyData class is :

```
public class MyData
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```